# print null value message to use if condition in while loop?

Tags: php

Get values from database and show the values, but i want to show value and also show empty message that means if no value in while loop then print message.
Here is my code, please anybody help me?

```
  /* database link */
  require_once '../db.php';
  $query = "SELECT id,first_name FROM ajax_user";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die('Could connect !');     
  /* loop */
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {               
        if($row['first_name']):                    
             echo $row['first_name']; /* no problem print those values */               
        else:               
             /* here is the problem, message doesn't print if (ajax_user) */
             /* table is empty */
             echo 'no value your database !!';     
        endif;            
   }
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Is there an error? Incorrect result?

Comment: my problem if  mysql_fetch_array($result) value is null, then print one message but don't .... how it is possible or not ?? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the no value in your database message outside of the while loop. If the fetch doesn't return any rows the code will skip the whole loop because the while condition is false.

Something like this...

```
  /* database link */
  require_once '../db.php';
  $query = "SELECT id,first_name FROM ajax_user";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die('Could connect !');  

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  if ($row):
    do  {               
        if($row['first_name']):                    
             echo $row['first_name'];                
        endif;            
     } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  else:
     echo 'no value your database !!';     
  endif;
```

Caveat: I don't work in PHP much, so the exact syntax may not be perfect here (PHP experts please edit my answer as necessary). However, the control flow should do what you need.